# What do I set the binary path for when using postgres via docker?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I'm trying to export table schema via pgadmin 4. I am running postgres in docker though so I don't have direct access to the filepath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting it to `/usr/bin` worked for me..

Comment: @cfnerd It may not be much of an answer, but it *is* an answer. It certainly doesn't  belong in the question, as it appears to be the solution to the problem.

Comment: Happiness doesn't always arrive in large packages.